# Save values of an array at Fortran 90 program

Tags: fortran90

I have a two-dimensional and 1-D arrays of different variables of a system which characterize an Equilibrium state of the system from where the next configurations going to evolve from. Now i need to save the data in these arrays at the specific situation and proceed, so how should i write on the declaration (the syntax) of the main program and also in the subroutine which use these arrays to be delivered to them by adjustable-size array method of passing arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Uuugh, sorry, but I'm not quite clear on what you are asking.

Are you interested in the SAVE statement, which enables a variable to retain its previous state, once for example, a subroutine is called again?

Comment: @Rook--exactly ! but note that the variable is array.